# After setting min-width on the cells in one column, table expands past edge of screen

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some HTML tables generated by a program I wrote. I had the `width` attribute set on all the cells in the first column because I wanted it to stay a specific width. In one of the files, however, it wasn't wide enough, so I figured it was because of a really long entry causing it to shrink to accommodate it. So I changed it to `min-width`. But now the whole table is expanding past the edge of the screen. What I want to do is have the first column fixed at 80 points wide, but the other two columns to be sized automatically based on their contents. But I don't want the table to be wide enough that you have to scroll horizontally to see the whole thing. Vertically is fine of course, for obvious reasons.

Here's the CSS I'm using (`td.time` refers to the table cells in the leftmost column, the one fixed at 80 points):

```
table              { border:none; }
tr:nth-child(odd)  { background-color:#eeeeee; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:white; }
td                 { padding:0; margin:0; }
td.stricken        { text-decoration:line-through; color:gray; }
td.time            { font-family:'Courier New', monospace; font-size:10pt; width:80pt; }
```

And here's a link to the HTML file that uses that style sheet and has the problem: http://norton1.dyndns.org/tppupdates/heartgold.html.

For those who are wondering, it's a list of everything posted to the Twitch Plays Pokémon HeartGold live updater on Reddit.

Comment: have you tried max width?

Comment: As @souvickcse said, all you need to do is put a `max-width`. You can apply this to either the table (`max-width: 100%`) or to the `td`s: `tr:nth-child(2) {max-width: 80%;}`

Comment: Adding `max-width:100%` to the table doesn't work, and I don't want to do anything "approximate" like 80%.

Comment: There is probably something in the second column that forces the column to be very wide. Try to find out what it is (maybe using divide and conquer).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela is correct.  I went through and I did a `table tr td div { display:none; }` and the table went down to normal.  It has something to do with a paragraph.  I even used `word-wrap:break-word;` just in case it was a huge link or something, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found you problem.  It's one of the dummies writing that they "dropped a whole bag of doritos."  Scroll down to 6/02/2014 12:32:35AM.  That line right there is causing your problems.

Add this to your CSS

```
table tr td div p {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

This will break entire words and links and make them not push the table out.

Comment: I added that to the CSS but it doesn't seem to make any difference! :-( Any idea why? And I'm aware I can fix that one entry manually, but I'd rather just have the table behave. Thanks though!

Comment: @flarn2006 It looks fixed.  Is it fixed for you? When you apply the CSS in the inspector it takes a long time since there are around 2000 entries.  I see you added that line to `dumpupdates.css` and it is applied for me.  If you still don't see it, you should try clearing your cache.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't fix it. What browser are you using? I'm using Firefox. I went ahead and accepted your answer though, as if it's working for you, it's probably fixed for other people too.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Mac OSX.  Thank you!  It is working on my PC as well, Chrome and Fire Fox